# How to call a getter or setter in python?

Tags: python

I have the following problem:

```
    self.myWrapper = wrapper.Wrapper
    self.myWrapper.set_entities(self.myWrapper, self.testEntity)
```

produces an error message, so does

```
 self.myWrapper = wrapper.Wrapper   
 self.myWrapper.set_entities(self.myWrapper, self.testEntity)
```

The error message is:

> TypeError: unbound method set_entities() must be called with Wrapper
>   instance as first argument (got type instance instance instead)

What is wrong here? Where is the difference ob an object instance and a type instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `wrapper.Wrapper` is a class, you need to actually initialize an instance.

```
self.myWrapper = wrapper.Wrapper()
```

Note the parenthesis.  Also, note this isn't a problem of getter/setter calling (though you should read up a bit more on Python if you are using the getter/setter pattern for member attributes, as it's not recommended in most cases in Python), but rather a problem of instance vs class and attribute access.

Comment: Jirg.....sry I am doing python for four weeks (before I used to do Java).

Comment: I know Java instantiates with brackets too - only I make silly mistakes when I learn sth new

Comment: Also you don't need to pass `self` explicitly; that's done for you.

Comment: @katrielalex Provided, of course, you are calling it as a bound (as a member attribute), not unbound (as a class attribute) method.